# find the min and avg of student if it exist show the name of the student

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

   int[] age = new int []{21,20,19,18,18,};
   String name [] = {"sofia","maria","john","Petra","mark"};
  int sum = 0;
  int avg;
  int min=age[0];
  int i;
  int counter=0;
  for(i=0;i<age.length;i++){
  if(age[i]<min ) {
            min=age[i];

  }




  avg= sum/age.length;

  System.out.println("the avarage of all Students are :"+avg);
  System.out.println("the minimum age of all Students : "+min);


    }
  for(i=0;i<age.length;i++){
  if (age[i] == min ) {
          System.out.println("the minimum age of all Students  : "+name[i]); 
        }

  }
}
```

}
// we have the (age) in the school and the (names) --> find "john" is  the name in the school to print "his age " if there are more than "one  john" print all the ages of  students call "john"   can anyone help me to solve this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a for loop to calcolate the sum of ages like this:

```
    for(i=0;i<age.length;i++){
        sum+=age[i];
      }
```

And take out this below block out of for loop:

```
  avg= sum/age.length;
  System.out.println("the avarage of all Students are :"+avg);
  System.out.println("the minimum age of all Students : "+min);
```

Like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

   int[] age = new int []{21,20,19,18,18,};
   String name [] = {"sofia","maria","john","Petra","mark"};
  int sum = 0;
  int avg;
  int min=age[0];
  int i;
  int counter=0;
  for(i=0;i<age.length;i++){
  if(age[i]<min ) {
     min=age[i];

   }
 }
  for(i=0;i<age.length;i++){
        sum+=age[i];
      }

  avg= sum/age.length;
  System.out.println("the avarage of all Students are :"+avg);
  System.out.println("the minimum age of all Students : "+min);
  for(i=0;i<age.length;i++){
  if (age[i] == min ) {
          System.out.println("the minimum age of all Students  : "+name[i]); 
        }

     }
    }
   }
```

Output:

```
 the avarage of all Students are :19
 the minimum age of all Students : 18
 the minimum age of all Students  : Petra
 the minimum age of all Students  : mark
```